# Download SharePoint Files-PowerShell Exception: The WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called from outside the overrides of the

Tags: powershell, exception, sharepoint, windows-server-2012

I am receiving the following error

> Get-PnPFile : The WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called from outside the overrides of the BeginProcessing, ProcessRecord, and EndProcessing methods, and they can only be called from within the same thread. Validate that the cmdlet makes these calls correctly, or contact Microsoft Customer Support Services.

when running this PowerShell script:

```
$cred = Get-Credential;
$webUrl = "https://...sharepoint.com";
$listUrl = "..";
$destination = "C:\\Folder1"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $webUrl -Credentials $cred
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$list = Get-PNPList -Identity $listUrl

function ProcessFolder($folderUrl, $destinationFolder) {
    $folder = Get-PnPFolder -RelativeUrl $folderUrl
    $tempfiles = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $folder -Property Files

    if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationfolder)) {
        $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -Type Directory
    }

    $total = $folder.Files.Count
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $total; $i++) {
        $file = $folder.Files[$i]

        Get-PnPFile -ServerRelativeUrl $file.ServerRelativeUrl -Path 
        $destinationfolder -FileName $file.Name -AsFile
    }
}

function ProcessSubFolders($folders, $currentPath) {
    foreach ($folder in $folders) {
        $tempurls = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $folder -Property ServerRelativeUrl    
        # Avoid Forms folders
        if ($folder.Name -ne "Forms") {
            $targetFolder = $currentPath +"\"+ $folder.Name;
            ProcessFolder 
            $folder.ServerRelativeUrl.Substring($web.ServerRelativeUrl.Length) 
            $targetFolder 
            $tempfolders = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $folder -Property Folders
            ProcessSubFolders $tempfolders $targetFolder
        }
    }
}

# Download root files
ProcessFolder $listUrl $destination + "\" 
# Download files in folders
$tempfolders = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $list.RootFolder -Property Folders
ProcessSubFolders $tempfolders $destination + "\"
```

This script works as expected on a Win10 PC but not on a Win Server.  Can anybody tell me what the reason could be please?

Answer (score 0):

After trying this again this morning, the above script works on both a Windows 10 PC and Windows Server,

Alexandra

Answer (score 0):

This may help people looking for that Exact Exception, in some cases. The Exception does not seem to explain what was actually happening  so here's some background for people to see if the situation is similar to mine:

It was Generated when I was using Powershell and `Get-PNPFile` to get files in bulk from a Sharepoint site. After some head scratching it seemed to be related to the existence of the file already being present on the local system from a previous download. Since the script was being used to keep a local copy of certain folders on the sharepoint site I was trying to overwrite the files locally if the server files were newer. (A bit like a crude rsync).

It appears `Get-PnpFile` does not clobber (silently overwrite) the file if it already exists, but generates this exception. A synopsis of the code that ran without error follows:

```
Try {
           $local_path = ($local_dir + $local_file)
           #test for the local file first and rename it
           if( Test-Path ( $local_path  ) -PathType Leaf ){
               Rename-Item $local_path ($local_path + '.old' )
           }

           #get the file
           Get-PnpFile -ServerRelativeUrl $file.ServerRelativeUrl -Path $local_dir -FileName $local_file -AsFile

            #remove the old file
           if( Test-Path ( $local_path  ) -PathType Leaf ){

                Remove-Item ($local_path + '.old' )
           }
    }
    Catch {
           #handle error and continue
    }
```

Essentially test for the local file first and rename it, download the file, delete the renamed local file. I wrapped it in a Try catch block so that if the download failed for this file I could continue as part of a loop and later I could search for any filenames with a .old suffix and recover the most recent local files for the failures, making note of those.

When the script was re-run  the script again which would not see the remote file locally (since the names wouldn't match and fetch a fresh copy but clear the .old  ( from a previous run ) file away if it succeeded in getting the file.

I didn't see the exception again.
Hope that helps somebody.

P.S. (if any of your files end in .old Strange/Unknown things WILL happen with the simple method above ....you have been warned)

**Update**
I'll update here whenever I see a new cause of this Exception

**Update** 
It appears "[" or "]" square brackets in the file name may also cause this. Perhaps in the URL needs urlencoding or escaping....